# VBA code auto hide/unhide continuously

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I need to hide/unhide rows as values are updated. Right now my code will auto hide as the value becomes zero, but if I enter a value it does not auto unhide.

```vba
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim LastRow As Long, c As Range

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each c In Range("F10:F56")
        If c.Value = 0 Then
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ElseIf c.Value = 1 Then
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you entering "a value", or are you entering a value of `1`?  Your code unhides only if the cell value is `1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try switching

```
ElseIf c.Value = 1 Then
```

to

```
ElseIf c.Value <> 0 Then
```

Right now it's checking specifically for cells that contain either a 0 in the first case, or a 1 in the elseif, and I assume you want it to hide on 0, and unhide on everything non-zero

Comment: Given that the `If` line is `If c.Value = 0 Then`, you don't need to say `ElseIf c.Value <> 0 Then`; just say `Else`.

Comment: Yes, good point. I was originally still skeptic that there might be criteria on the else case as well.